# [Solus Linux][Clion] Clion doesn't compile the simplest program

Tags: c++, linux, clion, solus

I downloaded Clion and all packages which I needed to work (I hope) and IDE doesn't compile "Hello World" program  :(

Code:

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    std::cout << "Hello, World!" << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Build errors:
    https://pastebin.com/J5UA9HpX

Any ideas? Regards, Dziura.

Sorry for bad English

Comment: Post code for hello world program.

Comment: Thanks for reply, done

Comment: Looking at the build errors, you modified by hand any include file below /usr/include ? This has nothing to do with CLion.

Comment: I didn't modify anything. Probably problem is inside distro